# What is difference between Bootstrap and Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap and Ruby On Rails are both web development frameworks.  What is the difference between them?  Why would you want to incorporate Bootstrap into Rails?

Answer (score 4):

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) and [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) are two different things.
Bootstrap is a client side framework. It helps you do things you'd usually do with CSS, JS and HTML.
Rails is a server side (mostly) MVC framework that is meant (I'm generalizing) to help you build database driven web applications.

You can use both together since Rails will take care of the Models, Controller and server side rendering of views, while Bootstrap will be incorporated into the views themselves and determine their appearance.

Comment: Thanks! @davidrac weel explained

Answer (score 1):

I think this question will be closed by mods, but there are two dimentions (although intertwined) in web; client and server, aka front and backend; The client side is basically about html, css and JavaScript, and the server side is handled by whatever language the server uses.

Ruby on Rails is a framework for the server side, and Bootstrap is a framework/library for the client side. They can cowork with ease, and they rarely (if ever) conflict.

Answer (score 1):

**Rails** is a full stack web framework - it has pretty much everything you need to create web applications. Rails runs on a web server and is written in Ruby.

This means it can store and retrieve information in a database and create dynamic pages.

It follows the [MVC design philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). Rails does not come with any styling at all*.

**Other popular MVC frameworks:**

- Django (Python)
- Express (Node.js)
- Pylons (Python)
- Laravel (PHP)

**Bootstrap** is front-end framework. It's basically just the frosting or decor on top of a web page or app - CSS and Javascript.

Bootstrap runs solely in the browser (except the build tools).

You can use Bootstrap by just adding:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

to a HTML page to use its build tools to customize the build.

It has styles and a few javascript widgets for common UI components. It "bootstraps" the app with some decent styling for rapid prototyping, beyond that it provides some structure so you can write less code. Although a common criticism is that all sites built on bootstrap tend to look "Bootstrappy".

**Other popular frontend frameworks:**

- Foundation
- Blueprint.css
- Semantic UI
- jQuery UI

## Conclusion

You can't really compare Rails and Bootstrap. The are different solutions to completely different problems. Bootstap was designed to work with rails but will work even with a static html page or any possible framework or CMS.

You could potentially combine any of the server side frameworks list with any one of the front-end frameworks listed.

Comment: * Not counting the "Welcome to Rails" default root page and error pages which do have some styling.

Comment: I have a feeling that your snippet for adding Bootstrap is actually adding Select2 for Bootstrap.

Comment: You're right @D-side. The Copy-Paste Monster ambushed me.